# What plant is this and how should we take care of it?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

I am sorry for my ignorance in advance. My wife has received this beautiful plant as a Christmas present. We love to know what it is, and more importantly, how we should take care of it to keep it alive as long as possible.Should we change its plastic pot?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! As Bamboo said, there's never a need to apologize. There are probably lots of people who have your plant and don't know what it is, so think of your question as a way of helping others. It's the same with all our questions, so keep on asking, and answering. We hope you have a great time here!

Comment: Just another comment, they are quite easy to propagate too, your local friendly search engine will give you all the info you need

Comment: Get that plant out of that pretty wrap!  Do not over water, do not allow the bottom of the pot to sit in water...

Comment: Do not repot for awhile.  When you do use a wider than tall CLAY pot and potting soil.  Don't soak this plant.  Shallow watering...lots of info on our site for more details.  Bamboo's link is a good one as is her answer.

Answer (score 10):

First, let me assure you there is no need to apologise for 'your ignorance'; you're not the first to not know a plant name and you certainly won't be the last! That said, this is Schlumbergera truncata, a forest type cactus plant,commonly known as Christmas cactus. It's relatively easy care; this answer here, whilst it does contain some slightly irrelevant information, has care information regarding this plant /[Blooming my Zygocactus houseplant](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30112/blooming-my-zygocactus-houseplant/30114#30114)